# WINLOAD.EFI CORRUPTED - Can't boot into OS normally, or via Safe mode and system restore won't work Windows 11

Tags: safe-mode, recovery, bcd, sfc

I can't boot into windows after a serious crash. Each time I boot, I get a critical process died or BSOD reporting different error codes around the BCD configuration file or winload.efi not being able to load or being corrupted I have attempted to repair my system files with SFC which scans my system and says it finds errors, says it repairs them, but after a reboot the critical process died crash continues. I have also followed several guides on how to rebuild my BCD using BCDedit and Bootrec commands but none have fixed my system not booting.

I am unable to restore my system using system restore off line as it claims it can't find saved restore points on my drive. I know the quick answer would be to reset my system, but recovery is also preventing me from doing that, and I really don't want to do that because I will have to re-download over 3 and a half TB of game pass games because a new installation of the OS would require their re installation. Games like MS Flight simulator took me over a day to reinstall earlier this month due to its size and how it installs on PC and I don't want to go through that all over again with my large games such as Ark, Flight Sim, Halo MCC, Gears 4/5, COD etc.

Prior to my system crash I was experiencing issues getting into safe mode and in the end I had to resort to using my windows 11 installation disk to do an upgrade of the system just to repair the recovery partition. It appeared to do the trick when my system was working but now I get two recovery environments - one which will not do anything when I press F1 or F8, and the other that gives me all the full F1 recovery options only to crash the system during boot when I select startup options, failures on resetting the system, rolling back updates, and refuses to find recovery points on my windows drive when I attempt system restore. I would normally restore my system from a system image backup, and I mean literally minutes before my PC crashed Acronis True Image formatted the wrong drive. I was using data retrieval software to recover the contents of that 4TB drive containing my system images before the major crash. I believe the initial crash was caused by either incompatible VGA drivers or me changing MSCONFIG from selective to full boot.  I have tried restoring the data off that drive but the system images are corrupted and wont mount. My only useful troubleshooting tool under the recovery environment is CMD. I know there is a fix for this using DOS command line arguments but I will need the help of someone familiar with the use of DOS in repairing boot sectors as I am not.

I suspect the boot errors and the broken recovery environment is largely due to me installing windows on top of an existing installation of windows or selecting normal boot through MSCONFIG, but without getting back into safe mode, I can't begin to reverse things I might have done to mess up my system.

HELP PLEASE. I have been trying to get my rig up and running again since the 6th August, and I want it up and running to play Starfield when it comes out.

Michael

Comment: Try a startup repair (which is not a reset):    https://www.elevenforum.com/t/use-startup-repair-in-windows-11.14660/    .... I don't think you tried that yet.